# Android LiveData: MutableData is never on active state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have the following `ViewModel`:

```
class SignInViewModel @Inject constructor(val api: BillingApi) : ViewModel() {
    val googleApiClient: MutableLiveData<GoogleApiClient> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

On my `Activity.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState: Bundle?)` I have:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    signInViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
            .get(SignInViewModel::class.java)

    signInViewModel.googleApiClient.observe(this, Observer<GoogleApiClient?> {
        ... // here never gets trigged
    }
```

Later on my code I have `signInViewModel.googleApiClient.value = it`. At this point (which happens after a button click, so I am in a resumed state) the I expected the `LiveData` to trigger my observer, but it **does not**.

While debugging I've noticed that my `MutableLiveData` is never on an `active` state.

What am I doing wrong? Please, I know I am using a `GoogleApiClient` instance in the example and that it should be initialized with the Activity with automanage and whatnot, but this is not the issue here. I want to set it dynamically and have my observer be triggered.

**Edit**: adding the code that calls the setValue

```
signInViewModel.someMethod(this)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(Consumer {
                // This gets called but the observe callback does **not**
                signInViewModel.googleApiClient.value = it
            }, errorCallback)
```

Comment: can you add code snippet having  `signInViewModel.googleApiClient.value = it` line?

Comment: Sure... it is a RxJava subscription. there is nothing especial about it, but here it goes (also emphasizing I've debugged it and the callback is called. Inside LiveData, the Observer is not considered active and therefore is not called.

Comment: See you are having problem with flow of your code in `SignInViewModel` class. You need to post whole `SignInViewModel` class. if you can not put all code then remove your business login in method but keep methods flow. With the info you have given no one can give a solution.

Comment: I've reproduced the error with the whole class you see in the post. Sorry but `SignInViewModel` is complete.

Comment: @Olinasc Just curious to know how are you able to inject billingApi without using any ViewModel Factory

Comment: There is a factory. I just removed it for avoiding discussing the fact. It follows the Github sample from google samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `minifyEnabled` was true. I haven't seen anything about proguard rules for architecture components.

Found this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62113696) which is not resolved yet but has the configuration needed to make it pass:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
```